# sharepoint Username won't show up

Tags: user-profile, active-directory

I have an issue with a specific user that sharepoint doesn't show his name.

For instance, if this user creates or edits an item in sharepoint, the value for "created/modify by" is alwayse empty.

Any idea where the issue comes from ? Active directory issue? User profile perhaps? I checked and noticed that this user has all needed permissions as other users. Thanks alot

Comment: Check his profile in upa...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The display name in Active Directory is where ours comes from. SharePoint then adds it to the User Information List when it does a profile sync. You may want to check your user profile sync and look up in Central Admin.